# Where are "active days"

Tags: support, profile-page

Love the new interface, but what happened to the "active" statistics? I looked under all of the Activity tabs, under the Profile view, etc., and don't see the info anywhere. There are participation badges tied to this information so it shoul be discoverable.

Comment: Sheesh. Small light font on my iPad and totally missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is on your *Profile* tab:

> [image: Screenshot of the *Profile* tab (tab hand circled) with line pointing to the *visited* stats]

The line is clickable, the same good ole' calendar is still there:

> [image: calendar for April 2015, with all days up until 16-04 highlighted]

Comment: Whoa. 1000+ days consecutive?!?

Comment: @CoolGuy: a [graph like this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-100297-Martijn%20Pieters.csv.png) doesn't just draw itself!